# Is the question's last activity relevant for editing, or accepting suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, review, suggested-edits

Is the last activity date of a topic relevant in deciding whether a given change makes the relevance threshold when editing, or deciding on a suggested edit?

[image]

Are smaller, less important edits fine with recently active topics, or do we not care about the changes to the front page when editing and use the same significance rule for all edits?

If the last activity date is relevant, could we establish some guideline about it?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be relevant - if the edit brings about a positive change in the post, by all means it should go through.

Comment: I'm asking as I tend to more readily accept edits that are minor grammar issues or just remove a "Hi", when the question is already on the front page. Things I consider too minor when applied to year(s) old posts.

Comment: @DanielBeck IMO activity date shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter. To a visitor or other users suggesting an edit, the post is always relevant, regardless of it being on some front page or not. However, I'd consider just removing "Thanks" too minor for a suggested edit, even on a new post ("Hi" is automatically removed from new posts anyway). @dan